# WP-Include rewrite directory

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules, apache, include

I try few day to rewrite wp-include directory but not success.

In `.htaccess` I add next line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^main/(.+) /wp-includes/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But not work and still in browser I see `wp-includes` directory.

Please can someone help.

Comment: If you are trying to "hide" the `wp-includes` directory then this is not something you can do by simply adding a rule to `.htaccess` (which you would also need to do). You need to configure WordPress itself to link to the desired URL without `wp-includes`.

Comment: I don't want to hide wp-includes I want just rename (rewrite) with .htaccess